# How to pass an Id to the controller from Blazor View in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, blazor

I am not able to pass an Id from a **blazor** view to the controller in an **Asp.Net MVC Application**

I tried to delete a value which is taken from db but i am not able to delete it the id is coming to the view  and i can able to list those values also but when i try to delete the id is not passing from view to the controller,The following are the code i have used

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@inject System.Net.Http.HttpClient HttpClient

<h3>DesignationList</h3>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            NumericId
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Slug
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Designation)
    {
     <tr>
        <td>
        @item.NumericId
        </td>
        <td>
        @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Slug
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Status
        </td>

        <td>

            <a href="Delete" asp-action="Delete" asp-route- 
           id="@item.Id" asp-controller="Designation">

        </td>
     </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
 </table>
@code {[Parameter] public 
IEnumerable<Global.Light.Time.Models.Designation> Designation { 
get; set; } }

 //Controller
   public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
    {
        var dynamicObj = new 
        DesignationRepository().Read(id);
        var retval = dynamicObj.Designation[0];
        return View(retval);
    }

    // POST: DesignationController/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid id, Designation 
    lookupDesignation)
    {
        try
        {

            var eleDelete = new DesignationRepository().Delete(id);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
     }
  }
```

please help me find a solution for this,Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code samples to the question - that will help other people undestand the issue and point the place where fix should be applied.

Comment: Your code is at the client.  You  send a request to the server and then get a response.  The response is a table which get displayed in the blazor view.  Your response still contains the data that you want deleted.  Which means the request did not remove the data from the server (or database attached to the server).  You problem is either the request is not formatted correctly or the server isn't processing the delete properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attributes on the controller methods to perform anti-forgery token validation but you have not supplied any anti-forgery token.

You'll need to use a form instead of a link to send back the token. Try using something like the following, swapping "ControllerName" with the name of your controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "ControllerName")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```